# Divide a circle DIV into four sector DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image]

How can I draw four sector DIVs (forming a circle) in HTML5 and CSS3 like the above figure and each div is clickable on its own area (not covering others)?

Comment: how? carefully. How have you tried?

Comment: Why DIVs? It is not the first thing that comes to mind when I think about circles.

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/6qj0mLnw/4/

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm going to write some JS code on the DIVs, and the contents inside those DIVs should be styled with CSS.

Comment: a 5sec search on the net and you get a ton of examples

Comment: another fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8twLp9jp/ - this one has the labels upright :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```css
.main{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:100px;
  margin-top: 125px;
}

.parent-div{
    width: 201px;
}

.parent-div div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:block; 
    margin: -1px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px;
}


.part1{
border-radius:100% 0 0 0 ;
float:left;
}
.part2{
border-radius: 0 100% 0 0 ;
float:right;
}
.part3{
border-radius:0 0 0 100% ;
float:left;
}
.part4{
border-radius:0 0 100% 0;
float:right;
}

.parent-div div span{
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font-size: 24px;

}
.parent-div .part1 span{
    top: 45px;
    left: 50px;

}
.parent-div .part2 span{
       top: 50px;
    left: 35px;

}


.parent-div .part3 span{
    top: 30%;
    left: 53%;

}
.parent-div .part4 span{
    top: 31px;
    left: 33px;

}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="part1"><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="part2"><span>2</span></div>
    </div>
  <div  class="parent-div">
      <div class="part3"><span>4</span></div>
      <div class="part4"><span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you could do that

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.circle{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.circle div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.circle div:nth-child(1){
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:100px 0 0 0;
}
.circle div:nth-child(2){
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:0 100px 0 0;
}
.circle div:nth-child(3){
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius:0 0 0 100px;
}
.circle div:nth-child(4){
  background-color:teal;
  border-radius:0 0 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: your labels are ... interesting